# how to clear data in struts2 session attribute without application server restart

Tags: java, jsp, session, struts2

In my application I am using struts2 and hibernate. In one of my service classes I used struts2 session for set an attribute and got that attribute in my jsp like this.
here is the java class portion:

```
 Map fileInformation = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
 fileInformation.put("checkFirstPart"," Hello ");
```

here is the jsp scriptlet:

```
<%
     Map recordedData2=ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
     String checkFirstPart = (String)recordedData2.get("checkFirstPart");
%>
<%
     if (checkFirstPart != null)
     out.println(checkFirstPart);
%>
```

the problem is by every time i run my project, session is not clear and shows all previous messages until I restart the application server. 
I used this also but it was not useful:

```
fileInformation.clear;
```

please help.

Comment: `recordedData2.invalidate(); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in your jsp page after getting the attribues:

```
recordedData2.clear();
```

I think this will solve your problem